# How to add public property to custom SqlMembership Provider to be configured in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, web-config

I am creating a custom SqlMembershipProvider class and I would like to have a new public property on it that would allow a user to set in the web.config along with the other public properties already apart of the SqlMembershipProvider base class. However when I add my property and try and run the application, I get the yellow screen of death error stating **Attribute not recognized 'DataLocationDescription'.**  What do I need to do to get this property accessible in the web.config with the other properties of the class?

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomSqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{


    public string DataLocationDescription { get; set; }

}
```

And here is the web.config file where I have my Property DataLocationDescription specified:

```
          <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider" 
           type="ClassLibraries.Web.Security.CustomSqlMembershipProvider" 
           connectionStringName="SQLConnection" 
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
           passwordAttemptWindow="30" DataLocationDescription="Tier2"/>
```

I tried using the ConfigurationProperty attribute but that did not make any difference.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("DataLocationDescription", IsRequired = true)]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Flea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `SqlMembershipProvider` the one that deserializes the membership/providers section in the configuration file, but the ConfigurationManager class. The schema for the `membership` element is [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so there's nothing you can do about it.

Simply put, the configuration system is unaware of your extra property.

Instead, you can create your [own configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and do a post-initialization of your custom membership provider somewhere at the beginning of your application.
So, you'd have something like a `CustomSqlMembershipProvider` section with one element for now (or attribute, your choice), the `DataLocationDescription` value.